# FancyWebSocket Not working in Safari, disconnected automatically

Tags: php, safari, websocket

i am making a multiuser real time chat web app using FancyWebSocket. 
[link is here](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat) . i follow the exact steps describe in their git repo, 
now as it says

You'll need IE10+, FF7+ or Chrome 14+ to run this example.

I wan to know , how i can run my webapp in safari ? because its "Closing / Disconnecting" after few seconds  and not allow me to "Open connection"

Values of WebSocket constructor in Safari is
[image]

- hope that help...

Answer (score 0):

Your WebSocket server is implementing an old and insecure version of the WebSocket protocol.

I would assume that the Safari developers have made the wise choice of not letting their users get pwnd.  All browser vendors should follow this example.

The solution is to use a different WebSocket server.  One that doesn't have huge, well published, trivially exploited vulnerabilities, such as any server that supports RFC 6455, which has been the published, established standard for nearly 4 years.